# reverse proxy in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, reverse-proxy

I need to build a reverse proxy to host a website that is running in an azure server. To protect the server and the URLs due to some bad design. That I cannot change.
I was thinking to call http://myhiddenserver.com/?id=11.11.11.111:9035
id is the IP and port for some special functions.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get the query parameters into the request.  The whole site runs off the same url http://{id}/setup.html. it reloads the main page via javascript and stays on setup.html.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "stunnelsetupdevice": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{id}"
            },
            "backendUri": "http://{id}/setup.html"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I tried to just make the proxy call the URL I am trying to build. This does not work either. The only way it works is if I put the whole URL into the backenduri.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "stunnelsetupdevice": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/"
            },
            "backendUri": "http://{id}/setup.html",
            "requestOverrides": {
                "backend.request.querystring.id": "11.11.11.11:9087"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a REST API service then you might want to look into _[Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)_.  It allows you to encapsulate as well as obfuscate somewhat services in the backend without exposing them directly

Comment: I started with API mgmt. I cant find documentation to explain how to do this.

Comment: see the link I posted.  There you will find a further link to documentation

Comment: As i already said, there is nothing in the documentation or the setup that shows how to change a query string parameter for my use case. even googling got me no where.  If you have a direct link to something else that will work. then ill take a look.

Comment: Ah I thought you were asking for doco for Azure APIM in general, not to worry

Comment: @SteveColeman Why not use Azure Application Gateway? Or create an Azure App Service and use its built-in ARR+UrlRewriting functionality...

Comment: @SteveColeman I'm trying to understand your "hidden" web-services' design... what is the purpose of the `id=` parameter... and why are you passing it IP addresses? What does the IP address represent? (And what happens if a user using only IPv6 visits?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use {*restOfPath} along with {id} here. According to the following MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#request-parameters

> **Route template parameters**
>
> Parameters that are used in the route template are available to be referenced by name. The parameter names are enclosed in braces ({}).
>
> For example, if a proxy has a route template, such as /pets/{petId}, the back-end URL can include the value of {petId}, as in https://.azurewebsites.net/api/pets/{petId}. If the route template terminates in a wildcard, such as /api/{***restOfPath**}, *the value {**restOfPath**} is a string representation of the remaining path segments from the incoming request.*

Try if something like this works for you:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "stunnelsetupdevice": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{id}/{*restOfPath}"
            },
            "backendUri": "http://{id}/setup.html/{*restOfPath}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that didn't work either and I updated my answer with something else i tried.